# Cannot install .NET on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, .net-6.0

I followed the official installation page for installing .NET 6.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 but I am not able to succeed.

The page told me to do:

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb

sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb

rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

And then:

```
sudo apt-get update; \
  sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
  sudo apt-get update && \
  sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0
```

I get the following result:

```
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dotnet-sdk-6.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'dotnet-sdk-6.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'dotnet-sdk-6.0'
```

When I do "apt search dotnet 6" the package dotnet-sdk-6.0/bionic is shown. But I am not able to install this, I get the same error as before.

I also tried installing with snap. But that is not working either. After giving it the alias dotnet (like was told on the installation page) I get the following: `/snap/dotnet-sdk/79/snap/command-chain/snapcraft-runner: 3: exec: /snap/dotnet-sdk/79/dotnet: not found`

Can somebody please help me with this? Or tell me the reason why it is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On what architecture are you running your ubuntu 18.04 ?

If you want to use dotnet 6, you also could download the binary file and install it.

Installation inside your home directory.

```
mkdir ~/.dotnet
```

```
cd ~/.dotnet
```

```
wget https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/17b6759f-1af0-41bc-ab12-209ba0377779/e8d02195dbf1434b940e0f05ae086453/dotnet-sdk-6.0.100-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

```
tar -xf dotnet-sdk-6.0.100-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet"
```

```
rm -rf dotnet-sdk-6.0.100-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Comment: Execute this command to make this change permanent : 
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/usr/share/dotnet"' &>> .bashrc

Answer (score 1):

if you upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04, first install SSL 1.0

http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.8_amd64.deb

and then follow standard instructions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#2110

------ EDIT

I now prefer a "portable" way of using several SDKs on the same Linux machine:

- download .NET 3.1 and .NET 6.0 as x64 binaries from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet
- Unpack the TAR.GZ files: dotnet-sdk-3.1.423-linux-x64.tar.gz and  dotnet-sdk-6.0.401-linux-x64.tar.gz currently
- Copy everything into a folder, e.g. /opt/dotnet; first .NET 3.1 then .NET 6.0; overwrite files if necessary
- Update your Bash/Zsh profile to point to their location

  export DOTNET_ROOT=/opt/dotnet

  export PATH=$PATH:$DOTNET_ROOT:$DOTNET_ROOT/tools
- Reboot and enjoy:

[image]